# Is there any figure about the accuracy of COVID-19 tests?

Tags: virus, test, test-results, covid-19

Recently I saw the local media (Romania) presenting a case that was initially considered COVID-19 positive and two subsequent tests led to negative results. As far as I know no official bothered to offer an explanation and I assume that this is expected in some cases (e.g. initial test was not done correctly).

Like any other tests, I expect to have an accuracy < 100% and I am wondering what that accuracy is for current tests.

I have read here about [the issues with US tests](https://futurism.com/neoscope/coronavirus-covid19-test-kits-broken-america-scarce-china) and [this article](https://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/asia/how-china-tests-for-covid-19-coronavirus-12438008) shows how tests are done in China:

> (..) the main way to test patients is using the Reverse Transcriptase
>   Polymerase Chain Reaction (RT-PCR) technique.

[This paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8862813-quantitative-rt-pcr-limits-and-accuracy/) deals with RT-PCR accuracy, but I cannot understand its conclusions.

<sub>By accuracy I mean (total tests - false positives - false negatives) / total tests.</sub>

Is there any figure about the accuracy of COVID-19 tests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How accurate are coronavirus tests?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21337/how-accurate-are-coronavirus-tests)

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX - yes, just that the question was asked 12 days after this one and it is strange that no one notice that it is a duplicate of this one. Thanks.

Comment: I also noticed it only now because of the new answer. I'll also flag the other as duplicate and let the mods sort it out.

Comment: @Alexei I've merged your question into the other one, which means the answers to this question are now merged into the duplicate. I went by which question had the most answers and comments, not by which was first.